# Нужна помощь с динамическим размещением элементов на панели в JavaFX

Tags: java, sql, javafx, fxml

Я только начал осваивать JavaFX.

Разрабатываю приложение, в котором можно создавать различные голосования. У меня есть задача - динамически размещать в панели названия голосований и кнопки, по которым можно будет перейти в другое окно и посмотреть подробную информацию о голосовании.

Насколько я понял технологию, нужно в обработчике события окна авторизации выгрузить данные с БД, затем загрузить FXML файл моего меню, и туда прямо из кода вставить мои кнопки и названия.

Проблема возникла в том, что у меня не получается получить панель, в которую я хочу вставить эти элементы. Правильный ли у меня ход мыслей касательно алгоритма добавления элементов, и где я ошибся?

Контроллер окна авторизации

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Objects;

public class LogInController
{
    @FXML
    private TextField loginField;
    @FXML
    private PasswordField passwordField;
    @FXML
    private Button loginButton;
    @FXML
    private Button signUpButton;
    @FXML
    private Text notCorrectInfo;

    @FXML
    void initialize()
    {
        loginButton.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            try {
                if (Database.authUser(loginField.getText(), passwordField.getText()))
                {
                    Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
                    Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("assets/menu.fxml")));
                    // Adding to votesPane elements
                    Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
                    AnchorPane pane = (AnchorPane) scene.lookup("#votesPane"); // Тут не получается получить панель (pane = null)
                    for (Vote vote :
                            Database.loadVotes()) {
                        Label name = new Label(vote.getName());
                        name.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
                        pane.getChildren().add(name);
                        pane.getChildren().add(new Button("Открыть"));
                    }
                    stage.setScene(scene);
                }
                else
                    notCorrectInfo.setVisible(true);
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

FXML-файл меню, куда я хочу динамически вставить элементы

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" styleClass="outerPane" stylesheets="@style.css"
            xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            fx:controller="sample.MenuController">
    <Button fx:id="createVoteButton" layoutX="435.0" layoutY="21.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="38.0"
            prefWidth="144.0" styleClass="greenButton" text="Create vote">
        <font>
          <Font name="Segoe UI" size="20.0"/>
        </font>
    </Button>
    <ScrollPane hbarPolicy="NEVER" layoutX="18.0" layoutY="80.0" prefHeight="306.0" prefWidth="565.0"
                styleClass="scrollPane">
        <AnchorPane fx:id="votesPane" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="306.0" prefWidth="565.0"
                    styleClass="scrollPane">
        </AnchorPane>
    </ScrollPane>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Ну во первых, блок initialize выполняется до загрузки апликейшн т.е у вас вспомогательное окно запустится раньше приложения, Во вторых, динамически менять FXML не получится, т.к идёт привязка к контроллеру. Но можно менять это из кода. В третьих что вы тут пытаетесь сделать, вообще непонятно.

Comment: Вы напишите конкретно, вам нужно панель сформировать 1 раз на основе загруженных данных с БД, или эта панель должна меняться постоянно сама.

Comment: @PerfectVoyage нет, данная панель должна формироваться всего 1 раз, я хотел инициировать её "сборку" при заходе в приложение, но не уверен, так ли это рекомендуется делать.

Comment: @PerfectVoyage Я выгрузил FXML в сцену и хочу получить доступ к внутренней панели, но метод lookup() почему-то не работает

Comment: Забавно обратиться к кнопке loginButton.setOnAction вы сумели, а к панели обратиться, решили почему-то, по другому =)

Comment: @PerfectVoyage так панель находится в другом fxml файле. LogInController.java относится к logIn.fxml, а menu — к другому контроллеру

Comment: @PerfectVoyage вы мне предлагаете собрать панель в начале тела init контроллера меню? Я просто в курсах по JavaFX читал, что initialize нельзя использовать для определения элементов интерфейса.

Comment: А вы разве не тоже самое пытаетесь сделать ? pane.getChildren().add(new Button("Открыть")); К тому же я описал вам конструкцию Platform

Comment: Блок initialize использовать можно, но грамотно, вы должны быть уверены что сначала сработает сборщик FXML, а потом подгрузятся остальные Node.  Пользователь этого не заметит, а в коде у вас проблем не возникнет.

Comment: Можно воспользоваться вспомогательным потоком, который будет отслеживать загружен ли контроллер, и подгружать туда свои NODE вариантов тьма, я вам самый простой описал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прежде чем мы начнем :

Замечания по коду :

- ScrollPane отсутствует fx:id
- Button не нужен fx:id, назначьте ему setOnAction. Имя метода должно соответствовать имени метода в контроллере.
- Вам не нужен lookup, у вас есть ГЛАВНАЯ ПАНЕЛЬ, прописанная в FXML, для этого fx:id и существует : связать ваш элемент с кодом.
- Настоятельно рекомендую почитать про MVC в JavaFX

  ```
   public class MenuController {

   @FXML
   private AnchorPane mainPane;

   @FXML
   private Button createVoteButton;

   @FXML
   private AnchorPane votesPane;

   public void initialize(){
       createVoteButton.setOnAction(e->pushButton());
   }

   private void pushButton(){
       System.out.println("Нажатие кнопки!!!!");
       // Можно заменить на setOnAction в SceneBuilder
       generete();
   }

   private void generete(){
       // Сделующий цикл генерирует случайное кол-во кнопок
       // Можно вызвать в блоке initialize, т.е загрузится само.

       for (int i = 0 ; i < randomDeleteThisTest(); i++){
           int finalI = i;

           Platform.runLater(()->{
               Button button = new Button("Button # = " + finalI);
               button.setLayoutX(finalI*50);
               // AnchorPane накладывает кнопки друг на друга без
               // явного указания setLayoutX
               mainPane.getChildren().add(button);
           });

           // Platform.runLater(()->{ // Ваш код });
           // Эта конструкция позволяет ОТЛОЖИТЬ изменения визуальной информации
           // они не происходят сию минуту
           // Использовать такое, без проверок, не совсем хорошо
           // Но сейчас в качестве примера сойдёт
       }
   }

   private static int randomDeleteThisTest(){
       Random r = new Random();
       return r.nextInt(15);
   }}
  ```

/////////////////////////////// FXML /////////////////////////////////

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" styleClass="outerPane"
        xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
        fx:controller="sample.MenuController"
        fx:id="mainPane">
<Button fx:id="createVoteButton" layoutX="435.0" layoutY="21.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="38.0"
        prefWidth="144.0" styleClass="greenButton" text="Create vote">
    <font>
        <Font name="Segoe UI" size="20.0"/>
    </font>
</Button>
<ScrollPane hbarPolicy="NEVER" layoutX="18.0" layoutY="80.0" prefHeight="306.0" prefWidth="565.0"
            styleClass="scrollPane">
    <AnchorPane fx:id="votesPane" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="306.0" prefWidth="565.0"
                styleClass="scrollPane">
    </AnchorPane>
</ScrollPane>
```

Comment: votesPane вам походу сюда добавить надо, лучше изменить это на какой нибудь FlowPane или VBox. Доступ так же, по fx:id